# Cómo ubicar un Layout debajo de otro Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Mi consulta es la siguiente. Quisiera saber si puedo acomodar un LinearLayout debajo de otro LinearLayout cuando ambos se encuentran dentro de un FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/img_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imgView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/layout_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#000000">

         <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text"Cerrar Vista"
            android:id="@+id/button1"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

El `RelativeLayout "layout_container"` cubre toda la pantalla del teléfono, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando se le de click al `Button` el `RelativeLayout` baje ó tenga un `marginTop` en base al tamaño del `img_container`.

Noten que no puedo usar valores fijos ya que se vería de distintas formas en distintos dispositivos. He leído algo sobre usar `CoordinatorLayout` pero no me ha quedado todo muy claro. Alguien tendría una idea mejor? Seria bueno usar un `Coordinator` y darle algún tipo de `Behavior` a esos dos `Layouts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día @rd_megs. La idea de usar Cordinator Layout me parece buena, todo depende de la embergadura de tu actividad. Pero para simplificarl el código puedes utilizar el siguinte ejemplo. Así quedaría

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout imgContainer, layoutContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        imgContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.img_container);
        layoutContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_container);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).
                setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
                        //Obtener la altura de img_container
                        int imgContainerHeight = imgContainer.getHeight();
                        //Valor de margen superior
                        int marginTop = 50;
                        imgContainerHeight += marginTop;
                        //Obtener la altura del frameLayout padre
                        int frameLayoutHeight = frameLayout.getHeight();

                        //Establecer la nueva altura para layout_container
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutContainerParams = layoutContainer.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutContainerParams.height = frameLayoutHeight - imgContainerHeight;
                        layoutContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutContainerParams);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Y así quedaría tu layout. Es casi igual al de la pregunta, pero le añadirías
layout_gravity="bottom"
a layout_container, para evitar que se superponga

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.infinityapp.stackoverflow.Main2Activity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_container">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/imgView" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/layout_container"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cerrar Vista"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero que mi respuesta te ayude, si tienes alguna duda me escribes e intentaré ayudarte. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Ariel!. Me ha servido para encaminarme un poco mas. Hice algunos cambios pero es lo que necesitaba! Mas adelante podria verlo de hacer con un CoordinatorLayout.